# How to output results from a for loop in a right way

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I am trying to output results from a for loop. It doesn't output the right way. I have pasted the results in the end of my code. It shouldn't echo out like that.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES); $i++) {
      $target_path = $_FILES[$i];

        if($i == 0 ){
        $test1 = $target_path;  
        }

        if($i == 1 ){
        $test2 = $target_path;
        } 

//This part should output only 2 results but it outputs something different.
        echo $test1." img 1 <br>";  

        echo $test2." img 2 <br>";
    }
```

It shouldn't output the following:

```
73c4d636e78bc7d33f90c182fc6ffaec.png img 1
img 2
73c4d636e78bc7d33f90c182fc6ffaec.png img 1
5eeb5c30fc9bba82e057953945b06eab.jpg img 2
```

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: 73c4d636e78bc7d33f90c182fc6ffaec.png img 1                                                                      
73c4d636e78bc7d33f90c182fc6ffaec.png5eeb5c30fc9bba82e057953945b06eab.jpg img 2

Comment: Could you specify what exactly you want it to output? Also, you `echo`ing `$test1` and `$test2` in all iterations (as they're not under `if` conditionals)

Comment: What does your array look like?

Comment: Do you understand that `$test1` value __never__ changes?

Comment: @u_mulder  I know. It is just the name of the file.

Comment: You probably want the echo statements inside the respective if blocks. Right now you print test1 and test2 for each run of the loop.

Comment: @jh1711, I see. How can I make them single results instead of being looped? But I still want both of the results.

Comment: @Giedrius, your comment solved the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES); $i++) {
  $target_path = $_FILES[$i];

  if($i == 0 ){
    $test1 = $target_path;  
    echo $test1." img 1 <br>";
  }

  if($i == 1 ){
    $test2 = $target_path;
    echo $test2." img 2 <br>";
  } 

}
```

Or:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES); $i++) {
  $target_path = $_FILES[$i];

  if($i == 0 ){
    $test = $target_path;  

  }

  if($i == 1 ){
    $test = $target_path;
  }

echo $test." img ".($i+1)." <br>"; 
}
```

Or:

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES); $i++) {
  $target_path = $_FILES[$i];

  if($i == 0 ){
    $test1 = $target_path;  
  }

  if($i == 1 ){
    $test2 = $target_path;
  } 

  if($i == 0 ){
    echo $test1." img 1 <br>";
  }
  //whatever
  if($i == 1 ){
    echo $test2." img 2 <br>";
  } 

}
```

Comment: This shouldn't work for my case. I must output the results outside of the if statement. I will use them in a seperate file which is included on the same page.

Comment: Gave you another two options. But of course @Rishi solution is the cleanest.

Comment: Thank you so much but I need the echoing outside of the if statements. It is the only thing I want. Without double results.

Comment: You can also put the echo statements outside the for loop (move the closing curly brace above the comment). Sorry for not thinking about that earlier

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this

```
  $target_path_arr = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES); $i++) {
    $target_path = $_FILES[$i];
    $target_path_arr[] = $target_path; // use this in future
    echo $target_path." img ". $i+1."<br>";
 }
```

Comment: 1
img 1
1
img 2
1
img 1
1
img 2 
Outputs this.

Comment: ($i+1) needs to be in brackets in the last line

Comment: :( Still the same: 94987c0d57600609227e4393ac93e302.png img 1
img 1
94987c0d57600609227e4393ac93e302.png img 1
img 2
a98ee8c0dfc5ad57cbcafbcb796017fe.jpg img 2
img 1
a98ee8c0dfc5ad57cbcafbcb796017fe.jpg img 2
img 2

Comment: All of it was in a for loop. I have solved it by Giedrius comment. Thanks.